# Why is ubiquity identity token nil on a device, but not on the simulator?

Tags: core-data, icloud

I'm trying to write a small iCloud / Core Data demo. It works on the sim, and those transactions appear to be showing up in iCloud. However, when I launch the app on a device -- and it launches fine -- the ubiquity identity token is nil. I'm signed into iCloud with the same user id as on the sim, the app is running, so ... what am I missing?

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated!